# Fullcalendar does not display events with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, fullcalendar

I am new to JavaScript and React and I would like to make a small calendar that retrieves events from an API and displays them in a calendar. The whole API and data recovery part works but I can't display the events on the page and I don't have any console errors

I created a page like this (I know that my code looks like spagetti code but I'm new to js)

```
import {
  IonContent,
  IonHeader,
  IonPage,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
} from "@ionic/react";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Home.css";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";

function convertirFormatDate(dateString: string) {
  const dateTimeParts = dateString.split(" ");
  const dateWithoutTimeZone =
    dateTimeParts[0] + "T" + dateTimeParts[1].split("+")[0];
  return dateWithoutTimeZone;
}

interface Event {
  title: string;
  start: string;
  end: string;
}

interface EventData {
  summary: string;
  start: string;
  end: string;
  description?: string;
  prof?: string;
  location?: string;
  uid?: string;
}

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState<Event[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://myapi/api/planning/getPlanningPerName/sample", {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        const events: Event[] = json.map((eventData: EventData) => ({
          title: eventData.summary,
          start: convertirFormatDate(eventData.start),
          end: convertirFormatDate(eventData.end),
        }));

        setEvents(events);
      });
  }, []);

  events.map((event: Event) => {
    console.log(event);
  });
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Mycalendar</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <div id="main-content">
          <FullCalendar
            plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
            initialView="dayGridDay"
            locale={"fr"}
            titleFormat={{ month: "long", day: "numeric" }}
            events={events}
          />
        </div>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

My events variable after processing is a list of json looking like this:

```
{
    "title": "my title.",
    "start": "2024-04-10T09:30:00",
    "end": "2024-04-10T11:00:00"
}
```

I would be very grateful if you have a solution.
(I know it's maybe a stupid bug)

Comment: Did you try exploring the format of data that FullCalendar component expects and Try to compare with the version of data that api responds ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the bug, full calendar doesn't like it when we inject events after loading the component, so you have to put a little "loading" before displaying them

```
  return (
    <IonPage>
      {events.length ? (<>
        // Render the calendar only when events are available
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle>EDT 4 RT</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <IonContent fullscreen>
          <div id="main-content">
            <FullCalendar
              plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
              initialView="dayGridDay"
              locale={"fr"}
              titleFormat={{ month: "long", day: "numeric" }}
              events={events}
            />
          </div>
        </IonContent></>
      ) : (
        // Display a loading indicator or placeholder while events are fetched
        <IonContent fullscreen>
           <p>loading</p>
        </IonContent>
      )}
    </IonPage>
  );
```

Comment: Unless you need the event data outside fullCalendar in your frontend, then it might be better to use fullCalendar's event feed functionality directly. That's also more flexible because it can fetch events on-demand - so only loading what's actually necessary for the date range being displayed, rather than downloading everything (much of which the user might never look at). Fullcalendar provides you with the date range information so your server can filter the events it returns appropriately. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function